# Forcing embedded tweet to 100% width

Tags: javascript, css, twitter, responsive-design

I'm trying to force an embedded tweet to behave responsively by setting its width to 100%.

I've attempted adjusting the width inline as follows:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" width="100%">...</blockquote>
```

I've also attempted styling the twitter-tweet class as follows:

```
blockquote.twitter-tweet {width:100% !important}
```

Both approaches have failed. Is this simply being overwritten by the script Twitter requires to be included with the tweet embed? (The script can be referenced at http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js.)

Any help in forcing the embed to 100% width would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cory, this is not possible using Twitter's provided embed. Well, it's possible to some extent, but only up to 520px. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines.

However, you can add width="2000" like this `

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" width="2000" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE">Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
```

`
And then adjust your CSS. It's not the best solution, though.

there's an old post that might be of use for you, don't know if still works, but worth a view, check it out at http://kovshenin.com/2012/quick-tip-how-to-make-tweet-embeds-responsive/

Answer (score 8):

Since May 2016 Twitter use an other embed HTML. It looks like this. They droped iFrame integration.

```
<twitterwidget class="twitter-tweet twitter-tweet-rendered" id="twitter-widget-1"
               style="position: static; visibility: visible; display: block; max-width: 100%; width: 500px; min-width: 220px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"
               data-tweet-id="732567624345915393">
    <div data-twitter-event-id="1" class="SandboxRoot env-bp-350" style="position: relative;"> 
        ...
    </div>
</twitterwidget>
```

In the DOM you will find an Element called `#shadow-root` after `twitterwidget` open tag (check out in *Chrome inspector*). From now it is possible to manipulate all Twitter Ebends by css and pseudo element shadow.

Example for width:

```
twitterwidget::shadow .EmbeddedTweet {
    width: 700px;
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

Example
- https://jsfiddle.net/86dc9y5t/

Do not use on product pages:
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM

Comment: this solution doesn't work, embedded tweet has width 500px

Comment: this looked promising to me too but no luck ;-/.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the width setting the width of the widget itself.

Check inspecting in the console what is the id of the widget container.

```
#twitter-widget-0{ width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the above solutions didn't work for me, it only worked when I queried `shadowRoot` and execute with delay after the tweet loads:

Javascript

```
setTimeout((function() {
  return $('.twitter-tweet').each(function() {
    return $(this.shadowRoot).find('.EmbeddedTweet').css({
      width: '99%',
      maxWidth: '100%'
    });
  });
}), 2000);
```

Coffeescript

```
setTimeout (->
  $('.twitter-tweet').each () ->
    $(this.shadowRoot).find('.EmbeddedTweet').css
      width: '99%'
      maxWidth: '100%'
), 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me.

Basically, you have to inject some css into your twitter widget iframe.

This example use jQuery

```
<style type="text/css" id="twitter-style">
  .timeline { max-width: 100%; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
twttr.widgets.createTimeline(
          'WIDGET_ID_GO_HERE',
          $('#widget-placeholder-go-here')[0],
          {
            chrome: 'nofooter noborders noheader' //optional
          }
        ).then(function(el) {
          $(el).contents().find('head').append($('#twitter-style'));
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The described solution with shadow seems to apply only to Chrome. For other Browsers it is posible to manipulte the with by javascript. Here is an Example with jQuery.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('.twitter-tweet').contents().find('.EmbeddedTweet').css({
            maxWidth: "960px", width: "100%"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is wondering why these solutions sometimes don't work; it's because twitter cards has a title and content with `white-space:nowrap`

But don't worry, this is the only code you will need to use, because it covers all cases (atm):

```
#twitter-widget-0,#twitter-widget-1{ width:100%; }

twitterwidget::shadow .SummaryCard-content *{white-space:normal !important;}

twitterwidget::shadow .resize-sensor{display:none !important;width:0px !important;overflow:hidden !important;}
```