# How Can I Replace 100% Width in the New Twitter Widget Using CSS code?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter

I currently have several Ruby on Rails applications where I use responsive web design via media queries. I used the following CSS code that overrode the width to 100%.

```
#twitter-widget-0, #twitter-widget-1 {

  float: none; 
  width: 100% !important;   
  font-size: 12px;

}
```

However I noticed in July 2015 that the Twitter widgets no longer display at 100% but a fixed size. I checked the developer website of Twitter and saw that the customization of Twitter widgets has been expanded. When I inspect the widget I see the CSS parameters that I have in my CSS but I also see a width set to 520px.

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

Looking at this link I know I can code the parameters right in the code with a fixed width. Not knowing the size of the screens that anyone may use to display my web applications I'm reluctant to set a fixed size anywhere. Another issue is that will not change it in my media queries.

The only link that I have found about customizing the current Twitter widget is the one below. Most of them are from 2011-2013.

[Twitter embedded timeline 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048815/twitter-embedded-timeline-100-width)

The question is asked by someone using the Twitter widget in Wordpress. The solution used jQuery. I am not adept enough in Javascript to implement a Javascript or jQuery solution so I do not know if it would work for me.

**UPDATED 7/16/2015 1100 GMT-5**

I decided to do another search this morning and found this [link](https://www.geekgoddess.com/change-twitter-widget-to-wider-than-520px/#comment-279) with three recent jQuery solutions that the people said they got to work.

I added the following line in `application.html.erb` to correct a ReferenceError for $. I though the jquery-rails gem would recognize my code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lightbe/v7xom6ms/). When I clicked JSHint and it said that my code was perfectly valid. The widget appears with a width of 552px. I'm not sure if the problem is where I have the code. I need help to determine why my jQuery code is not accomplishing my goal.

Here is the iframe statement when I inspect the Twitter widget:

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" allowfullscreen="" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline-block; position: static; visibility: visible; width: 520px;" title="Twitter Timeline" height="400">
.......widget statements.............
</iframe>
```

Comment: "Set the maximum width or the maximum height of an embedded timeline by adding a width or height attribute to the timeline’s anchor element."
have you tried to put a very large width on the link to see if it works?
as I see the width on the `<a>` works as a width but the widget have a max-width: 100%;

Comment: Did not work. When I read this again I realized that they said the max is 520px meaning that is going to be the widest width available. There may be a way around this. However I'm sure how I will override this in my media queries.

Comment: can you post a fiddle? it always help.

Comment: I have seen fiddles but I don't know how to create one.

Comment: just go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and add the html, css and js relevant parts. :)

Comment: Try width:100vw; that sets the width

Comment: @www139 do I replace what I currently have in my CSS or is the width clause within the twitter-timeline class?

Comment: I can't see the code too well right now because I'm on my phone, but I would look for all the containers that you want to be 100 and set them to 100. Remember that a percentage just sets the element of that percent of the parent's width, versus CSS vw sets it to a percentage of the viewport width and same with vh.

Comment: Yes I would replace you existing width code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based off of Kris's answer. This has an interval that checks to see if the iframe is available to manipulate. If so it fires the code and then clears the interval.

If you have multiple Twitter feeds use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    twitterCheck = setInterval(function() {
        if($('iframe[id^="twitter-widget-"]').length) {
            $('iframe[id^="twitter-widget-"]').each(function () {
                $(this).contents().find(".timeline").attr("style","max-width:100% !important;");
                $(this).attr("style","max-width:100% !important; width: 100% !important;");
            });
            clearInterval(twitterCheck);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v7xom6ms/20/

Or if you have one you can drop the `.each()` and use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    twitterCheck = setInterval(function() {
        var twitterFrame = $("#twitter-widget-0");
        if(twitterFrame.length) {
            twitterFrame.contents().find(".timeline").attr("style","max-width:100% !important;");
            twitterFrame.attr("style","max-width:100% !important; width: 100% !important;");
            clearInterval(twitterCheck);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v7xom6ms/21/

Edit: One could argue that the above code is prone to fail as well since the iframe is loaded but you can't confirm the content loaded. Easy fix. This also allows us to lower the interval for a less obvious resize transition.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    twitterCheck = setInterval(function() {
        var twitterFrame = $("#twitter-widget-0");
        var twitterTimeline = twitterFrame.contents().find(".timeline");
        if(twitterFrame.length && twitterTimeline.length) {
            twitterTimeline.attr("style","max-width:100% !important;");
            twitterFrame.attr("style","max-width:100% !important; width: 100% !important;");
            clearInterval(twitterCheck);
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7xom6ms/22/

Comment: Brad, Thanks so much! I have tried solutions 1 and 3. I placed the code in <head>. In all cases the widget is displayed with a width of 100%. The 1st time a page with the twitter widget is displayed the widget appears as expected. However subsequent times a page with a twitter widget is displayed one has to refresh the page to see the widget again. It looks like it may need to display the page each time as new somewhere. Maybe it's in the widget itself. Not sure though.

Comment: Brad, I did some more checking on the issue with multiple Twitter widgets. I decided to pull up another website of mine that uses Twitter widgets that I did not modify and have the same problem. The problem is outside of the JavaScript code you provided. I have checked your solution. I'm using solution 1 since I don't have any other iframes on the pages where Twitter widgets are displayed.

Comment: Note: I moved the script from application.html.erb to my assets folder in all my Rails applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the inline style of the div inside the iframe using jQuery using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#twitter-widget-0").contents().find(".timeline").attr("style","max-width:100% !important;");
$("#twitter-widget-0").attr("style","max-width:100% !important; width: 100% !important;");
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/v7xom6ms/9/embedded/result/

Comment: Just realized Firefox in JS Fiddle does not like the test, not sure if that is a fiddle problem or not, but seems to work on Chrome.

Comment: The first time I clicked your jsfiddle link it worked correctly (latest version of Safari/Mac). When I clicked the link again it showed it at 552px. That may be a bug in jsfiddle.

Should I put the script in <head> or on the page where the widget is? I originally had my code in <head> to cover any Twitter widgets in the website.

Comment: This isn't a bug with JSFiddle. The problem is the script you provided loads without establishing Twitter has injected the iframe on your page yet. So if your script beats Twitter the code above attempts to modify an iframe that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31961647/2046152

This solution works for me.

Basically, you have to inject some css into your twitter widget iframe.

This example use jQuery

```
<style type="text/css" id="twitter-style">
  .timeline { max-width: 100%; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
twttr.widgets.createTimeline(
          'WIDGET_ID_GO_HERE',
          $('#widget-placeholder-go-here')[0],
          {
            chrome: 'nofooter noborders noheader' //optional
          }
        ).then(function(el) {
          $(el).contents().find('head').append($('#twitter-style'));
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that single embedded tweets are different than embedded timelines.

To set a width of 550px or less, you can simply add a data attribute for the width to your `blockquote.twitter-tweet` element.

For a single embedded tweet & using jQuery, this worked for me to set the tweets to 100% width of the container:

```
$('iframe.twitter-tweet')
  .css('width', '100%')
  .css('max-width', '100%')
  .contents().find('.EmbeddedTweet').css('max-width', 'none');
```

It sets each iframe to 100% width, then removes the `max-width` on each `.twitter-tweet` div within each iframe contents.

*Edited 2016/1/13: Twitter changed the tweet CSS again*